# Is it normal that this html tag appears on Bounties in my profile?

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounty, profile-page

[image: <span title="2015-04-23 13:51:28Z" class="relativetime">in 3 days</span>]

I'm pretty sure this isn't expected.

Comment: Can you post link, so we can see it ?

Comment: @JonasCz It's in his profile in the bounties tab: http://stackoverflow.com/users/3178237/yerko-palma?tab=bounties

Comment: As @Kendra said, is in my profile

Comment: I don't know if someone else with a bountie open has the same issue, or if it's just me

Comment: It's easy enough to check if it shows up the same elsewhere, Yerko: Go to the featured tab, pick a question, check the bountier's profile. It appears to be globally broken, at least on SO. Probably just a bug with the new layout.

Comment: @Kendra you are right, it happens to all question, I guess is some missing close tag or something, I'm sure it will be easy to fix

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, maybe [it wasn't only a single place](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253959/115866)…

Fix is building out right now, double-encoding should be gone in a few minutes.